# Enviando um Array por POST com JSON para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, json

Seguinte, preciso enviar um array por POST com JSON. Já li sobre JSON.stringify e no meu código PHP utilizar o json_decode, mas na pratica não estou conseguindo aplicar. Vou colocar o código aqui e alterar ele mais ou menos com a ideia que espero, mesmo errado, mas apenas para facilitar derrepente o entendimento da logica.

HTML/Script

```
$("#ok").click(function() {
const nomes = ValorTextArea.value

var ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha = nomes.split('\n')   

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'busca.php',
        data: ***ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha***
        async: true,
            success: function(dados){
                //Retorno da pagina busca.php, como os dados vao vir em ordem a ideia é colocar em uma table, se retornar o valor fica do lado, se nao fica vazio.
                nome   |idade
                junior |23
                joao   |N/A
            }

    });
  });
```

PHP / SQL

```
include "conexao.php";

$nomes = $_POST['ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha']

for(var i=0; i< nomes.lenght;i++){
$select = "SELECT IDADE FROM clientes WHERE NOME" +$nomes[i];
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $select);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$idade[] = array_map('utf8_decode', $row);
}
echo json_encode($idade);
}
```

Peço desculpas se não consegui ser claro com a explicação ou usando a logica que espero junto com meu codigo. Esse é meu primeiro post.

Desde já, Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente seu código javascript e php contém **erros**, e possivelmente seja por isso que não está funcionando.

> A opção **data** da função **ajax** do jquery, recebe parametros entre
>   **chaves** e não por **asterisco**

Altere a linha:

```
data: ***ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha***
```

Por:

```
data: { ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha },
```

> Já no **PHP** na linha da variavel **$nomes** que recebe os dados
>   enviado via **POST** falta **ponto e vírgola** altere para:

```
$nomes = $_POST['ArrayNomesComQuebraDeLinha'];
```

> Também está **faltando** o sinal de **igual ( = )** o qual indica que a coluna **NOME** deve ser **=** a variável **$nomes[i]**
>
> No **PHP** para concatenar **string** não se utiliza o sinal de **+**, utiliza-se **ponto**

Ficando assim:

```
$select = "SELECT IDADE FROM clientes WHERE NOME = '" . $nomes[i] . "'";
```